# PWA Saving a photo taken without download prompt

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a progressive web app that utilizes the device camera to take pictures but want it to save to their Photos gallery without being prompted to download like the native camera app does..Is this even possible..I haven't discovered a way yet and not much info on google about it would it be different if it was uploaded to the cloud?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible... I mean, what if you went to a malicious PWA site and you wound up with a bunch of photos in your gallery without your permission?  It seems like a security issue.

Comment: I guess that is  true so then without pwa's having permissions granted to them they are always going to lack the power of apps

Comment: For what it's worth (and I know this is not the question you are asking) I began going down the PWA path a little while ago, and I was using Ionic.  All I learnt from it is to not use Ionic.  I know C# so I instead put in some hard effort learning Xamarin and the general responsiveness of the application and usability has increased out of sight.  Just my 2c.

Comment: Storage permissions would need to be ON for whichever browser is being used. (On Android at least - that I know)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The link at https://whatwebcando.today/photos.html suggests that this may be possible.

```
capturer = ImageCapture(streamVideoTrack)
```

Creates an image capturer out of the Media Stream Video Track.

```
capturer.takePhoto()
```

Returns a Promise resolved with the photo taken with the current settings.

```
capturer.setOptions(photoSettings)
```

Configures the photoSettings for subsequent captures; if visible, the effects of the configuration can be seen in the Track used as input.

This is the example code:

```
function getUserMedia(options, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  var api = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
  if (api) {
    return api.bind(navigator)(options, successCallback, failureCallback);
  }
}

var theStream;

function getStream() {
  if (!navigator.getUserMedia && !navigator.webkitGetUserMedia &&
    !navigator.mozGetUserMedia && !navigator.msGetUserMedia) {
    alert('User Media API not supported.');
    return;
  }

  var constraints = {
    video: true
  };

  getUserMedia(constraints, function (stream) {
    var mediaControl = document.querySelector('video');
    if ('srcObject' in mediaControl) {
      mediaControl.srcObject = stream;
      mediaControl.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(stream);
    } else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
      mediaControl.mozSrcObject = stream;
    }
    theStream = stream;
  }, function (err) {
    alert('Error: ' + err);
  });
}

function takePhoto() {
  if (!('ImageCapture' in window)) {
    alert('ImageCapture is not available');
    return;
  }

  if (!theStream) {
    alert('Grab the video stream first!');
    return;
  }

  var theImageCapturer = new ImageCapture(theStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);

  theImageCapturer.takePhoto()
    .then(blob => {
      var theImageTag = document.getElementById("imageTag");
      theImageTag.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    })
    .catch(err => alert('Error: ' + err));
}
```

So it seems like you can take a photo... I can't see anywhere to indicate that you can then persist this photo in the users storage though.  I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: How is that the question was "PWA Saving a photo taken without download prompt" then you start your answer with "The link [...] suggests that this may be possible." but then end it with "I can't see anywhere to indicate that you can then persist this photo in the users storage". So how does it suggest then, that you can but at the same time you can't.

Comment: Hm, in retrospect, this might have been a better fit on the comment on OP's question.  Then again, OP marked it as answer, so maybe it pointed them in enough of the right direction to accomplish their needs.